# What is the probability of a random line passing through a section of a shape.

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions

Start with a square which is divided into an even $n \times n$ grid of smaller squares.

The ultimate goal is to select $m$ squares from the grid so as to maximize the probability that a random line passing through the larger square intersects at least one of the selected squares.

An example is shown below where $n = 10$ and $m = 4$: the selected squares are coloured in red. The green lines are intersecting at least one of the selected squares, the grey lines are not. The orange lines are not intersecting the larger square so they are ignored. A line passing through the exact corner of a square is considered to have intersected all squares that share that corner.

[image: Example]

Even without doing any optimization, I can't figure out how to compute the probability for a given configuration. My thinking would be to come up with a parameterization of all lines that could pass through the larger square by selecting any two points from the large square's boundary but this runs into problems at the corners (there are a bunch of lines that can't be described in that way, but which pass through the exact corner).

My next thought was to instead select 2 points from a circle that is selected so that the square is inscribed within the circle, though this seems like it might skew the probabilities.

How would one go about parameterizing all of the lines which pass through a square?

Comment: How are you defining the probability distribution over the set of lines?  However you define that, you'd want to parametrize accordingly, so you can write down an integral representing the probability.

Comment: In other words, how would you pick a random line?

Comment: Adding to what @JairTaylor said, "how to pick a random line" is actually a historically famous "paradox" -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)

Comment: @antkam, thanks for the link. A very interesting and relevant read. It totally figures that I would try to use math to optimize a frivolous video game strategy and end up stumbling on a famous historical paradox...

Comment: @rnhuneau If you describe to us the rules of the video game, we might be able to figure to actually answer your question (at least approximately). This is why we ask users to provide context.